# NgbDatepicker: How to provide a ContentTemplate when using the datepicker in a popup?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I' am using a `NgbDatepicker` in a popup and I would like to apply a custom `Content Template` as shown in this example: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#custommonth

But I fail to do so:
To use the datepicker in a popup I have to apply the `NgbInputDatepicker` directive to an input. But I don't see a way to connect a `<ng-template ngbDatepickerContent>` with said input.
I also can't access the state of `NgbDatepicker` through the `NgbInputDatepicker`, which limits me in customizing the content.

Is it possible to use the `NgbDatepicker` in a popup with a custom `Content Template`? How would I provide the template to the `NgbInputDatepicker` and would I access the actual `NgbDatepicker`?

I forked and modified the example form the ng-boostrap project to better illustrate my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b43ppy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.html

Comment: hello, i'am having the same problem. did you find a solution please ?

Comment: Hi, sadly I never found a way to do it as I originally intent. I ended up placing my customization in the footer template, which definitely wasn't the solution I was looking for.
However I now think I look at it from the wrong perspective:
I stumbled over this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datetimepicker
It shows a custom input component/ ControlValueAccessor where the NgbDatepicker is placed in a regular popup, which should let you customize it any way you see fit. I haven't tried it with a Content Template yet, but that's the way I'll go in the future.
Hope that helps